# Append dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, resampling

If I have a pd dataframe with three columns: `id`, `start_time`, `end_time`, and I would like to transform it into a pd.df with two columns: `id`, `time`

e.g. from `[001, 1, 3][002, 3, 4]` to `[001, 1][001, 2][001, 3][002, 3][002, 4]`

Currently, I am using a for loop and append the dataframe in each iteration, but it's very slow. Is there any other method I can use to save time?

Comment: `start_time`, `end_time` is in seconds or it is in real data datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `start_time` and `end_time` is `timedelta` use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['001', 1, 3],['002', 3, 4]], 
                  columns=['id','start_time','end_time'])
print (df)
    id  start_time  end_time
0  001           1         3
1  002           3         4

#stack columns
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', value_name='time').drop('variable', axis=1)
#convert int to timedelta 
df1['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1.time, unit='s')
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
print (df1)
           id
time         
00:00:01  001
00:00:03  002
00:00:03  001
00:00:04  002

#groupby by id and resample by one second
print (df1.groupby('id')
          .resample('1S')
          .ffill()
          .reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
          .reset_index())

      time   id
0 00:00:01  001
1 00:00:02  001
2 00:00:03  001
3 00:00:03  002
4 00:00:04  002
```

If `start_time` and `end_time` is `datetime` use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['001', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-03'],
                   ['002', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-04']], 
                  columns=['id','start_time','end_time'])
print (df)
    id  start_time    end_time
0  001  2016-01-01  2016-01-03
1  002  2016-01-03  2016-01-04

df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', value_name='time').drop('variable', axis=1)
#convert to datetime
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.time)
df1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
print (df1)
             id
time           
2016-01-01  001
2016-01-03  002
2016-01-03  001
2016-01-04  002

#groupby by id and resample by one day
print (df1.groupby('id')
          .resample('1D')
          .ffill()
          .reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
          .reset_index())

        time   id
0 2016-01-01  001
1 2016-01-02  001
2 2016-01-03  001
3 2016-01-03  002
4 2016-01-04  002
```

Comment: But `start_time` and `end_time` appear to be `int` in time's clothing... So this won't work unless they are casted to some time format... I am investigating a way to do it using numpy and range and reshape.

Comment: Yes, but I think it is problem of sample - so I ask in comment if it is datetime and rather add two solutions. I am wondering for your solution.

Comment: Posted. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful. Just one issue, if I tried [001, 1, 3][001, 5, 6], I expect [001,1][001,2][001,3][001,5][001,6]. But your result returns [001,1][001,2][001,3][001,4][001,5][001,6]. Any solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Not a big issue in fact. I can just add an unique index to each row of the original dataset, and problem solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on your question:

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

reshaped = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['start time'], x['end time']+1)), axis=1).\
    stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
reshaped.columns = ['id', 'time']
reshaped
```

---

## Test

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""id,start time,end time
001, 1, 3
002, 3, 4""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, dtype={'id':'object'})
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print("In\n", df)

reshaped = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['start time'], x['end time']+1)), axis=1).\
    stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
reshaped.columns = ['id', 'time']
print("Out\n", reshaped)
```

Output:

```
In
    start time  end time
id      
001 1           3
002 3           4

Out
    id  time
0   001 1
1   001 2
2   001 3
3   002 3
4   002 4
```

Comment: Nice solution, only rather use `df = pd.read_csv(data, dtype={'id':str})`. My is more general, so I think slowier.

Comment: You timed them? I assumed yours would be faster because I am using the dreaded `.apply`... The `dtype` in `read_csv` will not affect anything, but I see your point, it will make it consistent. I shall update my answer.